# Huge java class for android project, how to split it up?

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

In C++ I'm used to being able to split classes up into multiple files using the scope resolution operator (::), but in java it seems impossible to split a class between multiple files.

I've read that classes shouldn't be more than a few hundred lines, but that sounds like ideological nonsense from people who don't write significant applications.

I am writing an industrial Android application (not for consumers, for technicians using professional test and measurement equipment in conjunction with the app linked via bluetooth) and several of my android activities are more than 1000 lines long and I'm not even close to being finished. The primary activity is over 6000 lines long and I expect it to become much longer still... It's becoming very unwieldy and, like I said, in C++ I would just logically split the class among multiple source files, but I guess that's not an option here.

Is there any alternative that I am overlooking to reduce the length of my source files without actually cutting out code (which is not an option...)?

Comment: Classes not being more than a few hundred line, while not being a hard rule, is a pretty good indicator of good design. I write back-end server applications with tens of thousands of classes and we manage just fine to keep 99% of them within that guide-line. In other words, if you're finding it an issue, there's a very good chance you should redesign your classes.

Comment: Maybe it's my inexperience with java, but all of this code relates to the android activity that is extended by the class (public class whatever extends Activity...). A lot of this code is event handlers that relate to the android activity, how would I split that up between different classes? I guess that's really my question.

Comment: I'd imagine these event handlers could (and should) be separate classes in their own right. You can also extract a lot of utility code to external classes (think of it as creating namespaces to group similar or related methods).

Comment: Hmm... I think I have some research to do. I assumed all code related to the activity had to be contained inside the class for that activity. This question is probably naive and due to my inexperience with Java and Android programming (I'm from a C/C++/ASM firmware background, kind of thrown into this project but having a ton of fun with it)

Answer (score 4):

It's acceptable to have a class with more than a hundred lines (most of my classes I write are more than 100 lines long). The thing is, dealing with an Object Orientated language, one should categorize as much as possible, to make the code `maintainable`, `intuitive` and `readable`. Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass your class. Make a base class with core functionality and subclass it. So you can have several files and at the end you have just one class you can use.

Comment: In order to do that (and I seriously think you shouldn't, sub-classing for this purpose seems like madness) while ensuring you couldn't end up with a broken instance that miss loads of methods you should at the very least make ALL classes except the last in the hierarchy be abstract.

Comment: I don't think that splitting one class over several files is a good idea at all ;). But subclassing would do the trick. The best would be to rethink the class design and split the large class in several smaller classes.

Comment: I'll look into subclassing, never heard of it before but at least now I have something to google :)

Answer (score 1):

you can still use composition and implementation techniques.  The Java *Package* is the same as C++ *Namespace*

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to separate common things in different classes, and then use instances of those classes on your Activities? Something like a [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), but a bit simpler.

Comment: I assumed that the On() methods related to an android activity (OnTouch, OnItemClick, etc) had to be contained within the class that implements that activity, is this not the case?

For example, here is one of my activity classes:
public class SomeClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener, OnGlobalLayoutListener, OnLongClickListener, OnItemClickListener

Then I have methods that handle those events, don't those methods have to be in the same class? Some of my activities handle far more events, and the code inside those handlers can be very long

Comment: Well, you can do this way, but you don't *have to* do this way. You can have one class to each listener, and implement your behaviors there. Your activity could be a parameter to your listeners. Actually, you can have one class with more than one listener interface (even all of them), but it doesn't have to be your activity.

Comment: I see, thank you, I'll try to figure out how to split this up... I'd actually like to have one class per listener that handles all Views that trigger that listener (example, all buttons that trigger OnClick events would be handled by one class that does nothing but handle all the OnClick events for my entire app)

Comment: If your "onClick events" have the same action for the entire application (or most part of it) it's a good idea to keep it in separated classes. Doing this will make your code more clean and split just like you want :)
You should take a better look on Java features, like subclasses, static fields, composition and more, but this is a good start! :)